# What c# classes and functions can be used in razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using ASP.NET MVC can be used the view engine Razor.

Razor let you use c# code after the `@` sign.

As example

```
@if (Model.Category == "watersports")
{
    <p>Splash!!</p>
}
```

Furthermore you can use something like `@DateTime.Now` for get the current time.
My question is: what functions can be used? From where Razor import them?

Comment: You _can_ use everything. But on the other hand, the View should be as simple as possible, so don't overdo it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any public class. They get imported with `@using MyNamespace`. You can also import them in the config file

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
```

element.

Comment: In my view code I don't have '@using MyNameSpace' but I still can use '@DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()'. Why?

Comment: Understood. The namespace was addeed in the web.config file. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use anything you want.  It's no different from code in a .cs file.  If you need to use something in another namespace that hasn't been added to your web.config already, you can add using statements just as you would in a .cs file.

`@using System.Collections.Generic;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use anything. Basically anything after @ is like writing in the code-behind. If you want code within your @ to not be seen as code, wrap it in a `<text></text>` block.